# sqoop import to s3 com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Couldn't initialize a SAX driver to create an XMLReader

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, sqoop

Using sqoop import mysql to s3, but it get `ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSClientIOException: getFileStatus on tmp/tb_room_type3/: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Couldn't initialize a SAX driver to create an XMLReader: Couldn't initialize a SAX driver to create an XMLReader, ..., Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities' is not recognized.`

the command is

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://address/mydatabase \
--username xxx\
--password xxx\
--table tb_room_type \
--target-dir s3a://my-bucket/tmp/tb_room_type2/ \
--hive-table tb_room_type2 \
--hive-database mydatabase \
--fields-terminated-by "," \
--hive-import --m 1 \
--hive-overwrite
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: is your jdbc configured properly? Is this the only flow failing or all of them failing? if all fails then config has issues.

Comment: @Koushik Roy, I didn't configure jdbc, and when I add s3 path, the error will occur. But it run correctly using hdfs path

Comment: I see, sqoop can write into hdfs but not directly to s3 which is simple file. Now. You can define hdfs on top of s3. That way you can use s3 to sqoop in

Comment: Sorry, What does defining hdfs on top of s3 mean? can you give an example? Thank you. @Koushik Roy